# Black lines while painting

Tags: texturing

I've seen similar questions being answered, but none of the solutions helped me.
Basically, there are black lines along the edges on my texture.

[image: Black lines along edges]

What I already tried:

- Increase bleed on brush - I increased it to a max of 8px, but it removed only a part of these lines
- Recalculate normals - didn't help
- Remove doubles - there was no doubles, so it didn't help
- Manual unwrapping - didn't help either

Btw I use Cycles render if it's important.

What else can I do? The only way I can get rid of these lines in to paint right on the uv map but it's really uncomfortable.

Help, please...

Also, with bleed maxed out, uv map looks odd:
[image]

Comment: Is you object scaled very high or very small? If so, it could be due to rounding imprecision. Try selecting the object and choosing Apply Scale and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If painting directly on the map, outside of the borders of your UV, fixes it, then it is a filtering/mipmapping issue that can be solved by increasing the bleed.

Don't worry about what your texture looks like out of the borders-- don't worry that it looks weird.  It's supposed to look like that.  That's not an odd image, an odd image is an image without any painted margins.

How much bleed should you use?  About half of the smallest distance between UV islands.  Ideally, your UV map is so well arranged that all verts of all islands are equally spaced and your entire image gets painted with bleed.

Increasing the bleed alone is not enough; it only paints bleed when you actually paint.  So in addition to increasing bleed, you need to actually paint over those edges again.  From the looks of your image, you painted, then increased bleed, then painted some more, but did not necessarily overpaint areas you already painted.  Which could easily explain your edges appearing only in some places....